# warning: initialisation from incompatible pointer type via function table in c

Tags: c

(code examples haven't been tested - just are for example)

I have several declarations like so:

```
void (* const a[])(void) = {func1, func2};
void func1() {};
void func2() {};
a[0]();
```

That compiles (if it was real code...) and the should runs func1.

However, if I want to pass arguments such as:

```
a[0](int 10);
```

Then I change my declarations:

```
void (* const a[])(int) = {func1, func2};
void func1(int foo) {};
void func2(int foo) {};
a[0](10);
```

That also compiles but I get the following warning:

```
warning: initialisation from incompatible pointer type.
```

The resulting code also runs fine, but I suspect that the declaration is at fault.
I can find several examples on how to build function tables that do not pass parameters but am struggling to find an example that shows how to do it with one.

Comment: Please make your [code sample](http://sscce.org/) complete & representative (which doesn't mean post all of your code).

Comment: Sorry for the poor example; wrote a proper one after and immediately hit the solution as per the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the declarations of `func1` and `func2` declare them as taking `void` as a parameter, rather than taking `int`.  You probably have

```
void func1(void);
void func2(void);
```

in some header file.  Instead, you need

```
void func1(int);
void func2(int);
```

This is because the declaration

```
void (*const a[])(int)
```

means that `a` is an array of function pointers taking `int` and returning `void`.

Comment: In the larger code I had many more functions and one of them didn't accept parameters. Doh.

Answer (score 3):

At the time you initialize `a`, `func1` and `func2` aren't declared, so they have the default type declarations of `int ()`. Declare `func1` and `func2` before initializing `a`.

```
void func1(int);
void func2(int);

void (* const a[])(int) = {func1, func2};
void func1(int foo) {};
void func2(int foo) {};
a[0](10);
```

Comment: We don't know for sure that they aren't declared.  This is just a small snippet from a file that could easily have `func1` and `func2` declared in an included header file.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: we also don't know they're declared, but declared incorrectly. The real problem is the code sample is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that having `typedef`-s for defining signature of functions make the code more readable. So why not:

```
typedef void signature_t(int);
void foo1(int);
void foo2(int);
const signature_t* funarray[] = { foo1, foo2 };
```